# Identity 2.2.1 & UserManager with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, asp.net-identity-2

I've been using Identity 2.2.1 with Ninject on a Web API project and all seems to be working well other than the UserManager. The UserManager is created but when it's injected into a service it only contains it's default implementation and not the configuration it should be using.

I've tried to follow multiple solutions to answers on here but to no avail. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong please.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();

        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        ConfigureOAuth(app, kernel);
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IKernel kernel)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManager>((option, context) =>
        {
            return kernel.Get<UserManager>();
        });

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(6),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true    // TODO: Change when in production
        });

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

**NinjectConfig.cs**

```
public static class NinjectConfig
{
    public static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
    }
}
```

**IdentityModule.cs**

```
public class IdentityModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<UserStore<User>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", new NeedsCollectorDbContext());
        Bind<UserManager>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

**UserManager.cs**

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public UserManager(IUserStore<User> store) : base(store)
    {
        UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        var dataProtectionProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
    }
}
```

The UserManager gets instantiated with the correct configuration within Startup.cs but when injected into the service later it's lost, please see the screenshots - the UserTokenProvider is null when injected.

[Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXeJg.png)

[Within a service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hWdW.png)

Thanks